Solution to $\Delta u = f(u)$ is non-negative when $u \geq 0$ on the boundary
Let $B_1$ be a ball of radius 1 in $\mathbb R^n$, and $u \in H^1(B_1)$ be a solution to $\Delta u = f(u)$ where $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$ is non-negative, and compactly supported in $[0,M]$. Assume that $u \geq 0$ on $\partial B_1$ in the trace sense. Show that $u \geq 0$ on $B_1$.
Here is my attempt.
By the elliptic regularity, $u \in C^{\infty}(B_1)$ (only used continuity of $u$ in this argument). Let $\Omega := \{x \in B_1 : u(x) < 0\}$ which is open. It suffices to show that $u \geq 0$ on $\Omega$.
Since $u$ is harmonic on $\Omega$, by the weak maximum principle from Gilbarg-Trudinger,
$$\inf_{\Omega} u \geq \inf_{\partial \Omega} u^-$$
So, it remains to show that
$$\inf_{\partial \Omega} u^- \geq 0$$
which is equivalent to $\min\{u, 0\} \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.
Suppose $\partial \Omega$ is Lipschitz, so that the trace of $u$ restricted to $\Omega$ is well-defined.
For $x \in \partial \Omega$, if $x \in B_1$, then one can easily deduce that $u(x) = 0$.
If $x \not\in B_1$, then $x \in \partial B_1$, and for $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$-a.e. $x \in \partial B_1$, $u(x) \geq 0$ by the assumption. Thus, for $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$-a.e. $x \in \partial \Omega$, $u(x) \geq 0$. This implies that $\min\{u, 0\} \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.
I would like to know a proof without making the strong assumption that $\partial \Omega$ is Lipschitz. I would appreicate any hint or reference.

Some comments on your proof:
In the third sentence, you say "since $u$ is harmonic" which it is not. My guess is that you mean to have $-\Delta u =f(u)$ instead of $\Delta u =f(u)$ (or you're using the 'geometer's Laplacian' i.e. $\Delta v:=-\sum_j \partial_{jj}v$), and you mean that $u$ is super-harmonic - then everything else makes sense.

Rough domains:
As you mention, an issue with your proof is that you use the classical maximum principle which requires regularity assumptions on $u$ that you don't necessarily want to impose. If you further assume that $u\in L^\infty(B_1)$ then, using that $B_1$ has smooth boundary and $f$ is smooth, elliptic regularity gives $u\in C^\infty(\overline{B_1})$, so your proof is correct.
Suppose we wish to prove the result on $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ an open, bounded, connected set (no regularity assumed). As far as I know, the issue here is the existence of a bounded trace operator $T:H^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\partial\Omega)$ requires at least some regularity assumptions on the boundary - the most common assumption is $\Omega$ Lipschitz though this can be relaxed. So part of the issue, is how do we express conditions on the boundary without the trace operator?
First of all, define $H^1_0(\Omega)$ as the closure of $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ with respect to the $H^1(\Omega)$ norm (not $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ with $Tu=0$ because we don't necessarily know $T$ exists), so no regularity on $\partial\Omega$ is required. Let $g\in H^1(\Omega)$. Then we say

$u \geq g$ on $\partial \Omega$ if $(u-g)^-\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ (using the convention $v^-=\max \{0,-v\}$, so $v^-\geq0$).
$u \leq g$ on $\partial \Omega$ if $(u-g)^+\in H^1_0(\Omega)$; and
$u=g$ on $\partial \Omega$ if $u-g\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ (or, equivalently, $u\geq g$ and $u\leq g$ on $\partial\Omega$).

Now, we've set up all the definitions to prove the result. Here's a proof that avoids regularity theory as well as assuming $u\in L^\infty(\Omega)$: Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ satisfy $$-\Delta u = f(u) \qquad \text{in } \Omega$$ in the weak sense and $$u\geq 0 \qquad \text{on } \partial \Omega $$ in the sense given above with $g=0$. By definition, $$ \int_\Omega\nabla u \cdot \nabla v \, dx = \int_\Omega f(u)v\,dx \qquad \text{for all }v\in H^1_0(\Omega).$$ Since $u^-\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, we can test $u$ against $v=u^-$ which yields $$0\geq-\int_\Omega\vert \nabla u^- \vert^2 \, dx = \int_\Omega f(u)u^-\,dx \geq 0 . $$ Hence, $$\int_\Omega\vert \nabla u^- \vert^2 \, dx =0 $$ which, since $\Omega$ is connected, implies $u^-$ is a constant. But then $u^-\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, so $u^-=0$ i.e. $u\geq 0$ in $\Omega$.

Thank you for your answer. I would like to clarify few things.
(1) In my question, $\Delta$ is defined as $\sum_{j = 1}^{n}\partial_{jj}^2$.
(2) I think $u$ is harmonic on $\Omega := {x \in B_1 : u(x) < 0}$ since $f(x) = 0$ for $x<0$.
(3) the maximum principle I was using in my proof works for $u \in H^1(U)$ where $U$ is open and bounded (need not have any regularity on $\partial U$).

My proof is to show that $u \geq 0$ on $\Omega := {x \in B_1 : u(x) < 0}$, which implies that $\Omega$ must be empty. Since $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ is harmonic on $\Omega$, it is a supersolution, thus it suffices to show that $u \geq 0$ on $\partial\Omega$ as defined in your answer (i.e. $u^- \in H_0^1(\Omega)$), since $\partial\Omega$ need not be Lipschitz.
